# Funduino USB Host Shield problems

Tags: arduino-mega, usb, spi, shields

I'm currently working on connecting a Funduino version of usb host shield onto an arduino mega board. But the serial output shows "osc did not start", which means the board can't find the shield. However the reset button works, so I estimate insufficient power being supplied.

[image]

I'm aware of the bridging solution for the regular arduino module for the 3.3v and 5v ([example](http://esp8266-notes.blogspot.com/2017/08/defective-arduino-usb-host-shield-boards.html)). But how can this solution be applied to the Funduino model.

Update: I've changed the SPI lines on the shield to the 6 ISCP pins on the Mega, but still no change in results.

I performed a second test using board_qc, which returned:

Circuits At Home 2011

USB Host Shield Quality Control Routine

Reading REVISION register... Die revision invalid. Value returned: 00

Unrecoverable error - test halted!!

0x55 pattern is transmitted via SPI

Press RESET to restart test

Comment: Please provide a link to the product page of that shield.

Comment: https://www.altronics.com.au/p/z6342-funduino-usb-host-shield/#/

Comment: https://fluxworkshop.com/products/ccaa100015-uno-usb-host-shield-keyes-red?variant=32458615783484

Comment: And can you please provide a link to the used library (and include either your sketch or point to the example code that you might be using)

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/usb-host-shield-library-2.0/ I used version 1.5 as shield requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shield communicates over SPI. However the SPI pins it uses are the "old" style (10-13) for the Arduino UNO.

The Mega doesn't use those pins, which is why the "new" style 6-pin SPI/ICSP header was added to boards.

You will have to manually jumper the right pins to the SPI pins of the Mega using wires.

Comment: Can you provide a pinout, so that I know where to make connections.

Comment: You would need to refer to the schematic or manual for the shield (which I don't have). The pinout for the mega is well documented.

Comment: I have tried connecting the SPI to the 6 pins in the center, but am still getting the same results.

Comment: I have also tried the SPI pins at the bottom of the Mega.

Comment: If the shield was designed for the Arduino Uno, then it would have a similar pinout to interface with it. So I used the Uno pinout as reference.

Comment: You should look for the actual pinout of the shield. You may have an interrupt signal to cope with, and there's no telling where any other logic signals may be...